# How to retrieve data from two table that are associated with a forign key in jsp from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

I have two tables in demo1 database. And i have to retrieve data from both of them. They have linked with foreign key. But when i tried i got data form only single table which is tbl1 but not getting data of referenced tbl2. So please help me for this. This is my code what i have done for this. There are two tables tbl1 and tbl2. And tbl1's primarykey id is given foreign key in tbl2,and tbl2's primary key is id_tbl2.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <%
            Connection con=null;
            Statement st=null;
            ResultSet rs=null;  
            try{
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo1","root","root");
              st=con.createStatement();
              rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT tbl1.name, tbl2.id_tbl2, tbl1.surname  FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id=tbl2.id_tbl1");
                             while(rs.next())
              {
                  out.write("</br>");
                  out.write(rs.getString(1));

                out.write(rs.getString(2));
                out.write("</br>");

                 out.write(rs.getString(3));
                out.write("</br>");

                out.write(rs.getString(4));
                out.write("</br>");
                           } rs.close();con.close();
             }catch(Exception e){
              out.write(" "+e);               
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you run your query outside your jsp application, do you get data?

Comment: Yes, i got data in mysql using query. But unfortunately not in jsp application.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is:

```
SELECT tbl1.name, tbl2.id_tbl2, tbl1.salary  
FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id=tbl2.id_tbl1
```

There are only 3 fields in the select statements.
But you are trying to read the 4th field which does not exist.

```
out.write(rs.getString(1));

out.write(rs.getString(2));
out.write("</br>");

out.write(rs.getString(3));
out.write("</br>");

out.write(rs.getString(4)); // this will result a runtime exception
out.write("</br>");
```

Remove the 4th, i.e. `getString(4)`, statement, and it should be working.

Comment: Thanks @Ravinder, I have removed that but still i am getting data from first table (tbl1) only. Not from tbl2.

Comment: Create both `tbl1` and `tbl2` with data on [*SQL Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com) and share with us.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `demo1`.`tbl1` (
  `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `surname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO tbl1(name,surname) values('abc','xyz'),('pqr','mnc'),('vbc','lmn'),('itl','quk');

Comment: CREATE TABLE `demo1`.`tbl2` (
  `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_tbl1` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `hobbies` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_tbl2`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tbl4_1` FOREIGN KEY `FK_tbl4_1` (`id_tbl1`)
    REFERENCES `tbl1` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


INSERT INTO tbl2(id_tbl1,hobibes) values('1','tennis'),('1','football'),('2','carrom'),('2','cricket'),('3','rugby'),('4','reading');

Comment: Why don't you create the same on [*SQL Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com) and share with us.

Comment: I have added query of my two tables. @Ravinder

Comment: Sorry i have tried in it but i can't create it. Please check my this query in MYSQL. Thanks. @Ravinder

Comment: Some of columns names used in java query are not present in these tables. Unless which, suggesting a solution is just a guessing and may not be correct. And waste of time as well.

Comment: Please check this query. I have correct it.@Ravinder

rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT tbl1.name, tbl2.hobibes, tbl1.surname  FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id=tbl2.id_tbl1");

Comment: @RonakJoshi: You better add your table structure and sample data to your posting rather than in comments. Also include expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your help i got the solution. I have done silly mistake in select query.